# Maximum object children on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, specifications, ecma

I'm aware that the ECMA script spec says that an object can have infinite children however I also understand many ECMA script implementations do not conform to this. I was wondering if node has a limit on the amount of children an object can have?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can but until heap out of memory.

```
var a = {};
var i = 0;
while(true){
    a[i] = null;
    i++;
}
```

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

So it depends on your memory size.